# Unity WebGL Build on Github Pages Error : unable to parse framework.js.gz

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to make a Unity game with WebGL and publish on github pages, but it caused the error. I googled it, but it wasn't very helpful because most of it wasn't about github page. I want to solve it. If you want to see the exact error code, https://r0k0r.github.io/FlappyBirdWebGL

Comment: The new versions of unity need a very specific setup on the web servers. Did you upload all the folders and is it setup on the webserver how unity requires

Comment: Yes I uploaded all folders. Can you tell me exactly what setups I need to? I'm new to unity

Comment: You will find unity has it well documented

Answer (score 2):

In the project settings you need to enable Decompression Fallback. After that the build will work.

[image: Decompression Fallback setting]